# Algebra - congruence relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, congruences

I suppose its not too complicated but I could find the answer or answer myself ....

Here is the problem:

> $x$ is a whole number
>
> $x<m$
>
> $x^{p_1} \equiv r_1\pmod{m}$
>
> $x^{p_2} \equiv r_2 \pmod{m}$
>
> find $x$

For example:

$x$ is a whole number

$x<33$

$x^{7} \equiv 29\pmod{33}$

$x^{13} \equiv 8\pmod{33}$

find $x$

Comment: I'm fascinated as to why you italicized the numbers.

Comment: I just copy&pasted the general problem (I used `mathit` for parameters) and replaced parameters to provide example. Thats why. I have just deitalicized numbers however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $7$ and $13$ are relatively prime, so there exists an expression of the form $7a + 13b = 1$.  Specifically $7\cdot 2 - 13 = 1$.

Now $(x^7)^2(x^{13})^{-1} = x^{7\cdot 2 - 13} = x \pmod{33}$ so $x = 29^2\cdot8^{-1} \pmod{33}$.  And here $8^{-1}$ doesn't mean $\frac18$, it means the number $0 \leq y < 33$ such that $8y \equiv 1 \pmod{33}$.

Do you know how to compute $8^{-1}$?  If you do then you're done.

Comment: You also need to *verify* that the result you obtain is a correct solution, since the original equations may be inconsistent, e.g. $\,x\equiv 1,\ x^2\equiv 2\ \ $

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose this would work if numbers are coprime and I know factors from Bezout's identity.

However if powers are non relatively prime, e.g 3 and 9. Is there way to calculate `x`?

My question was actually related to the RSA algorithm.

Comment: good point http://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque

Comment: If the numbers aren't relatively prime then you can calculate $x^d$ where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of the numbers.  That gives you an equation of the form $x^d = a \pmod{m}$ and any solution to this equation will be a solution to your original system of equations.  So there could be multiple solutions or, as Bill correctly points out, there could be no solutions.

Comment: Does that mean that I could not obtain x (in general) for non coprime numbers?

Comment: For non-coprime numbers whether there is a unique solution for $x$ depends on what $d$, $a$, and $m$ are.  For some values there will be no solutions, for some values there will multiple solutions, and for some values there will be a unique solution.

Comment: @dudelgrincen Beware that again it need not be true that "any solution to this equation will be a solution to the original system" (as claimed in a prior comment), since the original system can be inconsistent. The problem is that the derivation is $\rm\color{#c00}{unidirectional}$ $\ f(x)\equiv 0\equiv g(x)\,\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\,h(x)\equiv 0.\,$ This implies that the roots of the LHS must be roots of the RHS, but not necessarily conversely (for that you need a *bidirectional* implication, i.e. $\iff$ in place of $\,\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\,$ above).

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that if his interest is RSA encryption then the equations to decode a cipher text *are* consistent.